Surpyval Weibull goodness of fit
I have been using surpyval to fit some calibration data to a weibull distribution. I would like to assess the goodness of fit but I am not sure how to approach this. I had previously used "Reliability" library and this has a KS-test but I am not sure how to do this in Surpyval (Reliability does not support interval censored data). Code:
import surpyval as surv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#sample data
Fail = [1,1,3,1,5,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1]
Type = [1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1]
Time = [1820,1987,2176,[2373.0, 2542.0],2373,2731,[2920.0, 3093.0],2920,3279,[3472.0, 3641.0],3472,[3829.0, 4009.0],3829]

model = surv.Weibull.fit(x = Time, c = Type, n = Fail)
model.plot()
plt.show()

libraries:
matplotlib        3.6.0
numpy             1.26.0
scipy             1.14.0
surpyval          0.10.10

Included plot of the full dataset.
My full dataset has left,right, and interval data. Any other goodness of fit methods/pieces of knowledge would be very helpful and any insight on the image included.


A good quality control method for parametric survival models is to examine whether the distribution of scaled residuals matches what would be expected from the standard random distribution underlying the model family: minimum extreme value for Weibull, normal for lognormal, etc. That is, for an accelerated failure time (AFT) model of the form:
$$\log T = \alpha + \sigma W $$
(with $T$ the event time, $\alpha$  a location parameter, $\sigma$ a scale parameter, and $W$ the specified standard probability distribution), calculate residuals as:
$$ \frac{\log T - \hat \alpha}{\hat \sigma},$$
where $\hat \alpha$ and $\hat \sigma$ are the modeled estimates of those parameter values.
Then you handle censoring by performing survival analysis on the scaled residuals, taking advantage of the fact that a survival curve in general is just the complement of the cumulative distribution function. Annotate the residuals as to whether they are based on observed or censored events times. A Kaplan-Meier curve can handle the types of censoring that you specify, thus you don't need to restrict analysis to known event times. To check, overlay the Kaplan-Meier plot of scaled residuals with the corresponding survival curve of the underlying standard probability distribution.
Frank Harrell explains that approach in Section 18.3 of Regression Modeling Strategies. This page has a worked-through example. An advantage is that you don't have most of the data points scrunched together at the top right of the curve, as in the plot you show.
